# Find a basis for the set of invertible $3 \times 3$ matrices over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: linear-algebra

It's trivial to find the basis for matrices, but I cannot think out the basis for invertible matrices.

Comment: The space of invertible matrices does not form a linear subspace of the vector space of matrices of a given (square) size.

Comment: @Travis, Do you mean invertible matrices are not vector space themselves? So they surely do not have a basis.

Comment: Yes, in particular the set of invertible matrices is not closed under addition. For example, over any field $\Bbb F$, the identity matrix $\Bbb I$ and its negative, $-\Bbb I$, are both invertible, but $0 = \Bbb I + (-\Bbb I)$ is not.

Comment: @Travis Cool! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of invertible matrices is not a vector space over the field.

The easiest way to see this is that it is not even closed under addition: If $A$ is invertible, then so is $-A$, and $A+(-A)=0$ is not invertible.

Comment: Stupid autocorrect turned all my "invertibles" to "infertile."

Answer (score 0):

The zero matrix is not an invertible matrix, so the invertible matrixes do not form a subspace of the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: Okay, I'll just edit.